# The formal terminologies for saying one interval being contained in another interval with some distance at both ends

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I want to give an equivalent verbal description for the following thing:

$B=[0,1]$, $A=[\delta,1-\delta]$ for some small $\delta>0$.

I'm wondering if there is a terminology for describing this exact relationship between $A$ and $B$ in the example. The terminology I know that is most directly related to this is "$A$ is a proper subset of $B$", but this is not strong enough, as it doesn't exclude $A=(0,1)$, which is not what I wanted. So what's the appropriate terminologies or words I should use here?(It would be great if the terminologies or words proposed are general enough to be extended to $R^{n}$, the $n-$ dimensional Euclidean space). Thanks!

Comment: You could say $\overline{A} \subseteq B^\circ$ (the closure of $A$ is in the interior of $B$).

Comment: @JairTaylor Thanks, I guess this is what I want.